# Wordpress - check if there is an post to be published in future

Tags: wordpress

I need to check if there is an post to be published in future. I want to use WP functions, no directly access to database via mysql_query.

Has anyone some sample of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$count_posts = wp_count_posts();
$future_posts = $count_posts->future;
if($future_posts > 0)
{
    // future posts available
}
```

or

```
if(wp_count_posts()->future > 0)
{
    // future posts available
}
```

`wp_count_posts()` returns

```
stdClass Object 
( 
    [Publish] => 60 
    [Future] => 1 // only one is available 
    [Draft] => 9 
    [Pending] => 3 
    [Private] => 0 
    [Trash] => 0 
    [Auto-draft] => 3 
    [Inherit] => 0 
)
```

[**Reference**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts)

Answer (score 1):

$future_posts = get_posts('post_status'     => 'future');

Answer (score 0):

See the WordPress codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

For `post_status` fill in `future`

Comment: This is the right argument, but I think Koralek need to use `future`, not `draft`.